# Powershell - Combining Lines in Custom Objects

Tags: sorting, powershell

Currently I have a custom list that looks like this:

```
ItemPath ItemName LineNumber Indicator  Text
-------- -------- ---------- ---------- ------------
C:\      Test.txt 10         Reference  Hello World!
C:\      Test.txt 10         Difference Hell0 W0rld!
```

I want to sort or reorganize the list to look like this:

```
ItemPath ItemName LineNumber DiffText     RefText
-------- -------- ---------- ------------ ------------
C:\      Test.txt 10         Hello World! Hell0 W0rld!
```

Basically I want the lines joined by line number with the value of "text" labeled based on "indicator".  I am not having any luck figuring this out.

Comment: How did you generate/produce the list in the first place?

Comment: Hi!  I got the output from the Compare-Object cmdlet.

Comment: So the object is named allComparisons and I created it as part of a larger program, but the relevant commands are:

$NewItem = @{"ItemPath" = $ProdPath; "ItemName" = $ProdName; "Indicator" = $FormatedIndicator; "LineNumber" = $comparison.InputObject.ReadCount; "TextString" = $comparison.InputObject}

$Global:allComparisons += New-Object pscustomobject -Property $NewItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) to group the objects by path, name and line number, then combine the pairs into a single objects:

```
$pairs = $allComparisons |Group-Object -Property ItemPath,ItemName,LineNumber |ForEach-Object {

    # Grab the two objects in the group
    $Difference,$Reference = $_.Group |Sort-Object Indicator

    # Create a new object with Text properties from each
    New-Object psobject -Property $([ordered]@{
        ItemPath   = $Reference.ItemPath
        ItemName   = $Reference.ItemName
        LineNumber = $Reference.LineNumber
        DiffText   = $Difference.Text
        RefText    = $Reference.Text
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Let me try this out!

Comment: That really helped me out!  Thanks!